# how to open external link outside of my webView?

Tags: android, android-webview

**I made a website in php and I used webView to open as android app, I use external links on my site to open my whatsapp link. however only works when accessed by the browser the link that directs to my whatsapp, but does not work the link in my webView. 
appears net :: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, how to fix?**

```
   MainActivity
package com.example.programmingknowledge.sitehc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.example.programmingknowledge.easyonlineconverter.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://mysite/index.php#"); // 
        //myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //acrescentei zoom
       // myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
//AQUI BOTEI

        //AQUI TIREI
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");  //file:///android_asset/error.html

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            myWebView.goBack();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? do you want to load webview from your local url?

Comment: Have you tried by use of deeplinking?

Comment: I want the links that are not part of my browser open outside of my webView, for example the link to go to whatsapp I want it to exit the webview and go to whatsapp. and this only happens when I access my site through the browser. I did not use deeplink

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement custom webview client with condition of url which check current url contains matching text

```
class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("whatsapp")) {
                Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(launchIntent);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

For that, you must have to add **"whatsapp"** word in your URL for an open app.