# Is it possible to open a facebook group link in facebook app from android webview application build by android studio

Tags: javascript, android, facebook

I want to know is it possible to open a facebook group link in facebook app from android webview application build by android studio.

is there any html and JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

With webview in android studio, you can only open links inside your app and not outside.

In your case, you want a facebook group link to be opened in the facebook app which may not be possible using Webview.

That's why you need to use WebViewClient. You need to override **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method and start an intetn with the package "com.facebook"

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50293855/12802591

You may need to test if the user already had facebook app installed then open the group link there, if not it will open the group link inside the web view.

Another useful link :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54589702/12802591

Let me know if it works !

Comment: by using this its opening in another web browser not in the dedicated app.
please check.. which link i can use at new String[]{'   '}

public static final String[] OPEN_OUTSIDE_WEBVIEW = new String[]{"https://www.facebook.com/ID/"};

Comment: Yes it will open on browser and trigger a prompt to select which app you want to open the link, if Facebook app was already chosen to open urls with "facebook.com" by default it won't open the browser.